# Macports issue setting up RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rvm

Just setting up rails and RVM on a new laptop and i'm getting this error when running

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247',
please read /Users/#####/.rvm/log/1380821805_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

When running this

```
sudo rvm install ruby
```

Which produces this code.

```
[2013-10-03 13:36:45] requirements_osx_port_update_system
requirements_osx_port_update_system () 
{ 
    __rvm_try_sudo port -dv selfupdate || return $?
}
current path: /Users/matthewpetitt
command(2): requirements_osx_port_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247
DEBUG: Copying /Users/matthewpetitt/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to                 /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location:     /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out (60)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-    42/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after     rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar     /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 10
DEBUG: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: /Users/matthewpetitt/.rvm/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing     MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

I already have Xcode and Xcode command line tools installed. Anyone fixed something like this before.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and replace MacPorts with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized that it was just some network configuration at work that must have been blocking the ports. Check your network permissions or try a different network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure this command can be run first:

```
sudo port -dv selfupdate
```

This can be temporary network problem - if it is not follow the displayed instructions.